# Issue when accessing [facebook]standard_user_info in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fbconnect

I'm creating an iphone app using Facebook apis. I need to get the user's info. I mean, if I login first time I need to get the user ID, and user name of my account. I tried with

```
@"SELECT name, uid FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid = me()"
```

and

```
@"SELECT name, uid FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
```

but i got an error message.  (facebookErrDomain error 15.).
So how can I get the info, is there any permissions required for accessing it? I have got all of my friends details, now need to get mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer,

```
@"SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid = me()"
```

this method will return the users name and id.

Answer (score 1):

Did u try 'FROM user' ? And u can search error.

Comment: read this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info/